# How to set li to active in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have my navbar in a file called navbar.php which I include in each of the indiviual pages. I want to know how to add the active class to the button of the page that is selected using php. I have seen many tutorials of using jquery but since this happens on the page load there must be a solution without having to use jquery/javascript etc. So for example I have a line:

```
<li id="aboutus"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
```

I want there to be a line of code in aboutus.php which can change this earlier php code to

```
<li id="aboutus" class="active"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to add a class named "active" or you want to add an active statement `:active` to an element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for. It gets the page you're currently on. Afterwards it checks if the page is aboutus and then it echo active.

```
<?php
    $pg = $_GET['page'];
    ?>


    <li id="aboutus" class="<?php if($pg == 'aboutus.php'){echo 'active';} ?>"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
```

Comment: This works! for future reference for anyone you need to use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] instead of $_GET['page']

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in php you can just echo it

```
<?php 
    echo '<li id="aboutus" class="active"><a href="#">'.$yourString.'</a></li>';
?>
```

The file extension will be .phtml!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,it works for me,

```
   <li <?php if($id == your_id){ echo "class='nav visited'";} ?> >
```

Comment: once again this doesnt work because the code is executed before $id is set. Thanks though